# Checking the value of a decimal position

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the value of the 4th decimal place and check if it is a zero or not. If not I was planning on throwing an error message. For example 2.3189. I need to be able to check the value of the 4th decimal which in this case is 9. This is the code I have thus far. It seemed to be working for majority of cases but for example 1.2570. When I do the check for this number it says that the 0 is not a 0. When I do the same check with 1.2580 it says that the 0 is a 0. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
!!(submission && (quantity * 10000 % 10) === 0);
```

Comment: Numbers in JavaScript are *binary* floating-point values. That is, they're stored as a mantissa and an exponent, with the exponent being a power of **2**, not 10. Thus, you cannot reliably perform operations like what you describe, because base-2 fractions and base-10 fractions are different.

Comment: You can make the check more reliably by converting the number into a string and then finding whether the 4th character after the decimal point is `'0'`.

Comment: @Timo that is true, though depending on where the numbers come from there might still be surprising results (well, surprising to those who don't get how numbers work).

Answer (score 0):

I'd do regex checking 4th place after '.' to be zero

```
var number = 0.554156;
/\.[0-9]{3}0/.test(number.toString())
```

Comment: 1. A string converted to a string is still a string. The `.toString()` doesn't make much sense here. 2. This regex only matches digits if they do exist, `0.123` will not work even though it logically has a zero as a fourth digit after the dot.

Comment: Well of course it was supposed to be the number value... But I fixed it...

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of javascript expression for accessing the 4th decimal place since modulus operator has precision issues.

```js
const quantity = 1.2570;
console.log(Number(quantity.toFixed(4).split('.')[1][3]));
```

Comment: This method rounds the number mathematically. 1.25699 will say it is zero.